# Яндекс карты control.ListBoх, как убрать заголовок и оставить только список ListBoxItem

Tags: яндекс-карты

Стоит задача вывести на карту фильтр просто  виде списка. Без заголовка и скрытия/открытия. Как это сделать ? не могу найти информации

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ для [метода из песочницы](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager_filter) Яндекс — сдвинуть заголовок за карту:

```
myMap.controls.add(listBoxControl, {position: {left: 3, top: -33}});
```